# Complex Analysis: Infinite Products problem

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

I am currently trying to solve #3 here (taken from Lang's Complex Analysis):
[image: Lang Problem 2, 3]

I am not seeking the answer, I just have a few questions:

- Since $\alpha_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n^2}$, $|\alpha_n|$ is redundant, and I can simplify $\frac{|\alpha_n|}{\alpha_n}$ to be 1, correct?
- What does $\overline{\alpha}_n$ mean? I thought it might be complex conjugate, but $\alpha_n$ is not complex.
- Why do we need to know that $0<x<1$?

Comment: It is unfortunate that in the quoted problem (3), one has $\alpha_1 = 0$ which is forbidden by hypothesis in problem (2). One does have that the other $\alpha_n$ are positive real numbers, so yes, that fraction is $1$, and also each $\alpha_n$ is equal to its complex conjugate (being real). This problem is just a special case of the preceding problem. The problem is just focusing on particular values, so in this case he is considering only small positive real values of $z$ (they are still in the disk, so no greater than $1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first question, you're correct, since $\alpha_n$ is always real in this case, you can simplify $\frac {|\alpha_n|}{\alpha_n}$ to one

To your second question, you're also correct that $\bar {\alpha_n}$ denotes the complex conjugate, since $\alpha_n$ is real, the complex conjugate of $\alpha_n$ is just $\alpha_n$

To your third question, $0<x<1$ is important because it restricts the domain to values of $x$ where $f$ is defined